# How to provide modifier keys in lua?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

If I want to move a cursor one line down with Lua in Neovim I can use

```lua
:lua vim.cmd('normal j')
```

How do I move the screen down one line? For example, this does not work:

```lua
:lua vim.cmd('normal \<C-E>')
```

How to use modifier keys like Ctrl, Shift, Alt etc in such Lua commands?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble single and double quotes in Lua are pretty much the same

Comment: `:h nvim_replace_termcodes()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Matt suggestion, something like this seems to work:

```lua
  local down = vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes('normal <C-E>', true, false, true)
  vim.cmd(down)
```